# Google static maps multiple custom marker icons

Tags: google-maps, static

I'm trying to get multiple custom icon markers on one map. I know how to make one (icon=...) but I only get the last one multple times... See image below, I created markers "Test 1", "Test 2" and "Test 3" but only "Test 3" shows up...

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cohKG.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can add this way: `markers=icon:`*path_to_the_image*`|`*lat*`,`*lng*

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap
?center=52.446925,4.815730&zoom=10&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap
&markers=icon:http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/integers/60/number-one-32.png|52.373670, 4.896718
&markers=icon:http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/integers/60/number-two-32.png|52.489908, 4.658677
&markers=icon:http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/integers/60/number-three-32.png|52.553214, 4.673812
&key=API_KEY
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** [The Google Static Maps API does not support custom icon URLs that use HTTPS; the default icon will be displayed.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#CustomIcons)

**Edit 2:** [Google Supports custom marker points](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#CustomIcons)

Comment: Very important the lack of support of HTTPS  if this helps, you can upload your image to tinyurl and remove the s on the https and it will work, thanks for the advice